# The Unknown Segmentation Fault on brute-force tool

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, brute-force, crypt

```
// gcc -o OUTPUT Input.c -lcrypt
// Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<crypt.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

int findShadowIndex(char *inputUserName, char shadow[][500]) {
    int i = 0; // Tempory Loop variable

    char *userName;

    while (shadow[i] != NULL) {

        strcpy(userName, shadow[i]);
        userName = strtok(userName, ":");

        if (!strcmp(inputUserName, userName))
            return i + 1;

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void setBFValue(char BFValue[]) {
    int i, j = 0;

    BFValue[j++] = '\0';

    for (i = 48; i < 123; i++) {
        if (i >= 58 && i <= 64)
            continue;

        else if (i >= 91 && i <= 96)
            continue;

        BFValue[j] = i;

        j++;
    }

    BFValue[j++] = '!';
    BFValue[j++] = '@';
    BFValue[j++] = '#';
    BFValue[j++] = '$';
    BFValue[j++] = '%';
    BFValue[j] = '^';

    return;
}

int bruteForcing(char *originHash, char *cryptSalt, char *userName) {

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0;// Brute Force Loop variable

    char passwd[7] = "";

    char BFValue[100] = { NULL, }; // Brute Force Value
    setBFValue(BFValue);

    for (a = 0; a < 69; a++) {
        passwd[5] = BFValue[a];

        for (b = 0; b < 69; b++)
        {
            passwd[4] = BFValue[b];

            for (c = 0; c < 69; c++)
            {
                passwd[3] = BFValue[c];
                for (d = 0; d < 69; d++) {
                    passwd[2] = BFValue[d];

                    for (e = 0; e < 69; e++) {
                        passwd[1] = BFValue[e];

                        for (f = 1; f < 69; f++) {
                            passwd[0] = BFValue[f];

                            //printf("\nPasswd : %s\n\n", passwd);
                            //printf("\ncryptSalt : %s\n\n", cryptSalt);
                            //printf("\userName : %s\n\n", hashID);
                            //printf("\noroginHash : %s\n\n", originHash);

                            printf("%s, %s\n", passwd, userName);

                            //printf("%d, \n", strcmp(originHash, crypt(passwd, cryptSalt)));

                            if (!strcmp(originHash, crypt(passwd, cryptSalt))) {
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("[-] User Name : %s, Password : %s\n", userName, passwd);
                                printf("\n");

                                return 1;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
    //printf("\n[-] Decryption Failed\n\n");

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fd = NULL; // Shadow File Descripter

    int i = 0; // Tempory Loop variable

    char shadow[100][500] = { {NULL, } }; // List of Shadow File

    char userName[30]; // User Name
    int shadowIdx; // User name index in Shadow File

    char* ptr; // Tempory char pointer

    char *id; // User ID
    char *hash, *hashID, *hashSalt, *hashValue;

    char cryptSalt[100] = "$";
    char originHash[100];

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("\n[!] Usage >>> sudo ./yu_cracker [Shadow File] [User Name]\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (argc == 3) {
        fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (fd == NULL) {
            printf("\n[!] Can't find Shadow File!!!\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while (!feof(fd)) {
            fgets(shadow[i], 500, fd);
            i++;
        }

        strcpy(userName, argv[2]); // Get User name

        shadowIdx = findShadowIndex(userName, shadow);

        if (!shadowIdx) {
            printf("\n[!] Can't find user name in Shadow File\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        ptr = strtok(shadow[shadowIdx - 1], ":");
        id = ptr;

        ptr = strtok(NULL, ":");
        hash = ptr;
        strcpy(originHash, hash);

        ptr = strtok(hash, "$");
        hashID = ptr;

        ptr = strtok(NULL, "$");
        hashSalt = ptr;

        strcat(cryptSalt, hashID);
        strcat(cryptSalt, "$");
        strcat(cryptSalt, hashSalt);

        ptr = strtok(NULL, "$");
        hashValue = ptr;

        printf("[+] Origin Hash >>> %s\n\n", originHash);

        printf("[+] Hash ID >>> %s\n", hashID);
        printf("[+] Salt >>> %s\n", cryptSalt);
        printf("[+] Hash Value >>> %s\n\n", hashValue);

        int result = bruteForcing(originHash, cryptSalt, userName);
    }

    else {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

This code is a simple brute force tool for /etc/shadow.

First, copy the /etc/shadow on somewhere directory && chmod 777 [SHADOW]
Second, get the specific hash value on file from input user name (Hash ID, Hash Salt, Hash Value)
And then, select the candidate value and calculate hash with crypt function (#include <crypt.h>) in loop
If calculated hash value is same with candidate value, print decrypted text and return result
It seems to be working fine, but occur segmentation fault after printed the decrypted text
Please can you explain to me why segmentation fault is occured?

I hope these code and picture helps to you solve this question

[How to RUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdXt7.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i5Ko.png)

Comment: Hi. You may `malloc` your `username` in order to reserve memory space.

Comment: can you put the text output instead of a picture?

Comment: BTW, try valgind, it will spot the error immediately

Answer (score 0):

## Fixes

I've fixed your code, I'll first show you my modifications and then I'll explain them:

Your `findShadowIndex` function becomes:

```
int findShadowIndex(char *inputUserName, char shadow[][500]) {
    int i = 0; // Tempory Loop variable

    while (shadow[i] != NULL) {
        char currentShadowRow[500];
        strcpy(currentShadowRow, shadow[i]);

        if (!strcmp(inputUserName, strtok(currentShadowRow, ":"))) {
            return i + 1;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and `char originHash[100];` becomes `char originHash[500];`.

## Explanation

### In `findShadowIndex`

In your oginal `findShadowIndex`, on the first iteration, when you called `strcpy(userName, shadow[i]);` you were copying characters from the address `shadow[i]` into the memory location `userName`. The issue is that `char *userName;` didn't represent memory you had allocated so `strcpy` was writing to memory you didn't own, causing a segfault.

My version copies the current shadow line you are examinating into a local buffer (`char currentShadowRow[500];`) and then calls ``` strtok`` on the copy as to not modify the ``` shadow``` array that is used later.

### Enlarging `originHash` to 500 bytes

The `originHash` array wasn't big enough to fit all hashes (my password's hash was bigger than 100 characters).

## Working Version

If you want to copy/paste the working code, here you go:

```c
// gcc -o OUTPUT Input.c -lcrypt
// Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<crypt.h>

int findShadowIndex(char *inputUserName, char shadow[][500]) {
    int i = 0; // Tempory Loop variable

    while (shadow[i] != NULL) {
        char currentShadowRow[500];
        strcpy(currentShadowRow, shadow[i]);

        if (!strcmp(inputUserName, strtok(currentShadowRow, ":"))) {
            return i + 1;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void setBFValue(char BFValue[]) {
    int i, j = 0;

    BFValue[j++] = '\0';

    for (i = 48; i < 123; i++) {
        if (i >= 58 && i <= 64)
            continue;

        else if (i >= 91 && i <= 96)
            continue;

        BFValue[j] = i;

        j++;
    }

    BFValue[j++] = '!';
    BFValue[j++] = '@';
    BFValue[j++] = '#';
    BFValue[j++] = '$';
    BFValue[j++] = '%';
    BFValue[j] = '^';

    return;
}

int bruteForcing(char *originHash, char *cryptSalt, char *userName) {

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0;// Brute Force Loop variable

    char passwd[7] = "";

    char BFValue[100] = { '\0' }; // Brute Force Value
    setBFValue(BFValue);

    for (a = 0; a < 69; a++) {
        passwd[5] = BFValue[a];

        for (b = 0; b < 69; b++)
        {
            passwd[4] = BFValue[b];

            for (c = 0; c < 69; c++)
            {
                passwd[3] = BFValue[c];
                for (d = 0; d < 69; d++) {
                    passwd[2] = BFValue[d];

                    for (e = 0; e < 69; e++) {
                        passwd[1] = BFValue[e];

                        for (f = 1; f < 69; f++) {
                            passwd[0] = BFValue[f];

                            //printf("\nPasswd : %s\n\n", passwd);
                            //printf("\ncryptSalt : %s\n\n", cryptSalt);
                            //printf("\userName : %s\n\n", hashID);
                            //printf("\noroginHash : %s\n\n", originHash);

                            printf("%s, %s\n", passwd, userName);

                            //printf("%d, \n", strcmp(originHash, crypt(passwd, cryptSalt)));

                            if (!strcmp(originHash, crypt(passwd, cryptSalt))) {
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("[-] User Name : %s, Password : %s\n", userName, passwd);
                                printf("\n");

                                return 1;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
    //printf("\n[-] Decryption Failed\n\n");

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fd = NULL; // Shadow File Descripter

    int i = 0; // Tempory Loop variable

    char shadow[100][500] = { '\0' }; // List of Shadow File

    char userName[30]; // User Name
    int shadowIdx; // User name index in Shadow File

    char* ptr; // Tempory char pointer

    char *id; // User ID
    char *hash, *hashID, *hashSalt, *hashValue;

    char cryptSalt[100] = "$";
    char originHash[500];

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("\n[!] Usage >>> sudo ./yu_cracker [Shadow File] [User Name]\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (argc == 3) {
        fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (fd == NULL) {
            printf("\n[!] Can't find Shadow File!!!\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while (!feof(fd)) {
            fgets(shadow[i], 500, fd);
            i++;
        }

        strcpy(userName, argv[2]); // Get User name

        shadowIdx = findShadowIndex(userName, shadow);

        if (!shadowIdx) {
            printf("\n[!] Can't find user name in Shadow File\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        id = strtok(shadow[shadowIdx - 1], ":");

        hash = strtok(NULL, ":");

        strcpy(originHash, hash);
        hashID = strtok(hash, "$");

        hashSalt = strtok(NULL, "$");

        strcat(cryptSalt, hashID);
        strcat(cryptSalt, "$");
        strcat(cryptSalt, hashSalt);

        hashValue = strtok(NULL, "$");

        printf("[+] Origin Hash >>> %s\n\n", originHash);

        printf("[+] Hash ID >>> %s\n", hashID);
        printf("[+] Salt >>> %s\n", cryptSalt);
        printf("[+] Hash Value >>> %s\n\n", hashValue);

        int result = bruteForcing(originHash, cryptSalt, userName);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I hope this answered all of your questions!